# Length of value issue with unique ids

Tags: pandas, append

I am trying to write a simple code and haven't found a simple answer for this. I am trying to assign a unique ID to each person based on when the file was amended and their employee ID. Then add the column of Unique IDs to the file.

```
excel1 = "Book1.xlsx"
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel1, header = 0)
time = time.strftime('%m%d%Y%H%m', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime ("Book1.xlsx")))
unique_id=[df1["ID"] + time]

df1["CID"]=unique_id
```

When I try to run it I keep getting an error of

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Could anyone have an answer on this?

Comment: Remove the list `df1["CID"] = df1.ID + time`. Otherwise you are trying to set a column based on a list whose only element is a Series.

Comment: welcome to SO Alex. I don't understand what you want. Do you want to create a new column in the data frame (containing data on the files) and creating a unique ID storing when it was last edited and the employee ID of the last user who edited it?

Comment: @zero that's correct I am going to have users go in and edit the file and when there is a new change I will have the script check the file and append it with new data and a unique ID based on when the file was updated